# Higher resolutions unavailable with 2.6.38-8 kernel

Tags: 11.04, xorg, kernel, resolution

After upgrading to Natty and the 2.6.38-8 kernel I could no longer obtain the 1920x1080 resolution available in Maverick with 2.6.35-22. In fact the boot occasionally hung. However, after selecting the remaining 2.6.35-22 kernel, the high resolution was available.

I then made the mistake of completely reinstalling, but could never get the higher resolutions with 2.6.38-8, no matter what I did. e.g. trying the nvidia proprietary driver, creating an xorg.conf. Even from the command line using

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1 1920x1080_60.00

xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

all I would get would be a blank screen and the monitor reporting no input. (Low resolutions displayed fine with xrandr.) I could actually add the 1920x1080 to the already existing probe-reported resolutions in the pool of available resolutions, but choosing it would give the blank screen.  In the end I installed the 2.6.35-22 kernel again. The high resolution is back.

For a while there, staying up all night and trying many things, I thought that a new video board or monitor might be needed, but deep down, I knew that they were both OK.

My question is - "Is this some bug involving the latest kernel, that will go away, or if this persists in future kernels, is there a way to make sure that I can keep my native resolution?"

Comment: +1 for sure, I'm also 1920x1080 and I have been struggling with http://askubuntu.com/questions/12578/adjusting-display-geometry-in-a-virtual-machine - Still no solution!

Comment: 1920x1080 was automatically selected for my Acer G215H with an Nvidia GeForce 210 card.

Comment: I have no problem too with GT240 and my new 1920x1080 monitor

Comment: So it is possible that the latest version of nouveau does not work with a particular video card (nVidia GeForce4 MX 440 AGP 8x), but the previous versions did, and if I want to use the latest kernel I have to buy another card, even though this one is otherwise fine for my purposes?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

No guarantees, but you might try installing the latest kernel from the Kernel PPA; I have an Intel video system, but that fixed several problems I had. Check out:
https://launchpad.net/~kernel-ppa/+archive/ppa

Comment: Thank for the suggestion Bryan. I didn't know where to find new, unreleased, kernels. Now I'll give them a try and keep trying until one of them works. I feel better about doing that than locking myself into the 2.6.35-22 kernel.

Comment: It may also be helpful to know that if you need to boot an older kernel, hold shift as you boot and the Grub menu will pause so you can select it.