# Incorrect screen resolution on login on a MacBook Pro 7.1

Tags: 11.04, xorg, nvidia, mac

I'm having trouble with x11...when I restart my laptop, the screen resolution is always reset to 1024x768.

I set the resolution to the appropriate 1280x800 and everything is fine for that session, until I restart or re-login. Then the screen is reset back to 1024x768. Saving the x configuration file after resetting the resolution doesn't help.

I'm using Nvidia's "Current Version" in the Addtional Drivers and making changes qwith "Nvidia X Server Settings"
Ubuntu 11.04 MacBook Pro 7.1

Any ideas about what I could do to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Try with xrandr command. Please take a look at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/12578/adjusting-display-geometry-in-a-virtual-machine

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem, ubuntu would set the right resolution from xorg.conf, but after login the resolution would change.

If you go to Monitors in System Settings, select the resolution that you would like, and after click on "Make Default".