# Headless machine: Increase Remote Desktop resolution

Tags: resolution, remote-desktop, vnc, remote-access

I have a headless Ubuntu machine that I connect to with a combination of ssh and vnc.

When I've got a monitor attached (which is rare), the vnc connection is the full resolution of the attached monitor (of course).
But, when I connect using vnc when there's no monitor connected, I get a much lower-resolution connection than I would like. It's as if the computer has a tiny monitor connected.

I have looked through Settings and haven't found anything promising (resolution was grayed out without a monitor connected).

**How can I change the 'virtual resolution' that I get when I connect using VNC?**

### Update:

**I'm not interested in recommendations for other vnc software now, I just want to know how to do the above with the built-in vnc server.**
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

By using the default Gnome vino-server we are stuck to the running X-Server geometry. If  for any reasons we do need to run the vino-server we can only change the display geometry by defining a **[custom X-Session](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution)** for this VNC usage or change the geometry live e.g. with **randr** as described in principle in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12578/adjusting-display-geometry-in-a-virtual-machine/12618#12618).

However doing so has some disadvantages that need to be considered:

- if predifined We are unable to run this custom session when another monitor is connected.
- Other X devices may need to be defined as well.
- changing the geometry for a VNC session remotely cannot easily be done.
- **if we break our X settings we may end up with no display**

If we do need adjustments in screen geometry it would therefore be a better advice to install a VNC-server package other than vino that is capable of changing the geometry.

---

If we use [vncserver](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/vnc4server.1.html)/[Xvnc](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/Xtightvnc.1.html) from either [tightvncserver](http://packages.ubuntu.com/tightvncserver) [image: Install tightvncserver], or [vnc4server](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vnc4server) [image: Install vnc4server] we may define a virtual XServer geometry by simply adding the option `-geometry <width>x<height>` when invoking.

After having installed one of the packages above on the remote we start it there by e.g.

```
vncserver :1 -geometry 1024x720
```

In this example a display with number 1 is created having 1024x720 pixels (after entering a password for the connection). This can be accessed from the local machine by

```
vncviewer <remote_ip>:1
```

Use option `-via` when connecting with a SSH session.

Comment: Ok, that sounds good. But, if at all possible, I want to do this with the built-in vnc server.

Comment: @Takat Re: your update, I need to use vino because the computer that connects to it is a Mac, so I can't install the software you mention above. If you can set up vino to use a higher resolution, please do tell me how. Thanks.

Comment: @Nathan G.: I can't test this - no Mac here - but vncserver uses the same protocol as does vino. From Ubuntu you also use the same client (vncviewer). There should be no reason for a MAC to not display the desktop that comes from xvnc/vncserver. Before you take the pain of diving into XServer configuration I'd at least give it a try. For tightvncserver it's 1,901 kB disk space and you will be able to purge it w/o further dependencies (vnc4server is ~5 MB).

Comment: Tested with a mac, works fine.  If you have it running on `:1`, simply use `vnc://servername:5901` to connect.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered to try an NX technology?, like FreeNX or NXnoMachine ?, it can be more friendly and configurable

Answer (score 2):

I don't no if this can be an easy solution in Ubuntu too, but i had the same problem with Linux Mint 18.2(ubuntu derivative) and using VNC-viewers on linux, windows and android

After some testing i cam e up with the following solution (at least working for my situation):

I made a script file (for example called 'SetResolution1280x1024.sh' ),
containing these lines:

---

$ #!/bin/bash

$ xrandr --fb 1280x1050

---

and saved it in one of the user folders.
Then made it executable 
(rightclick>properties>permissions and check the box 'allow executing file as program')

Then i made it execute at startup:

Menu -> System Settings -> Startup & Shutdown -> Autostart

Click: 'Add Script'

searched for the folder where i put the scriptfile, and clicked 'OK'

Then i selected the option to start it 'Pre KDE'

(executing it just 'at startup' did not work properly, so i guess the resolution has to be set before the desktop starts, otherwise you end up with a small desktop on a large screen.
This last thing also happend when executing the script from the active desktop !)

This worked for me, without disrupting my system (wich i did trying the 'dummy driver':)

May this will help some others

Jeroen

Comment: Awesome Man. Thanks for the command. It worked for me.