# Ubuntu 11.10 unable to reconize monitor while running in VM

Tags: virtualbox, resolution

I'm currently running Ubuntu 11.10 64bit in a VirtualBox VM and for some reason it has be stuck at 1024x768, with the monitor being unrecognised (shows as unknown). Is there a way to tell Ubuntu that I have a monitor that can show a higher resolution and hence obtain more real estate for my VM?

Comment: Install [Guest Additions](http://askubuntu.com/q/22743) see also [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12578/adjusting-display-geometry-in-a-virtual-machine/12618#12618)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@canadiancreed have you tried installing the VirtualBox Guest Additions? That will allow you to add a virtual driver for your monitor so that different resolutions can be supported. In my experience with VBox, that has shown to be a game-changer for usability.

HTH. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did, but I'll verify tonight. With the amount of VMs bouncing around there's a chance it might have been missed

Answer (score 1):

Hey go for following link
http://www.sysprobs.com/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-ubuntu-11-10-2d-and-3d-unity-issues

hope this helps

Naveen Arora