# How do I add available resolutions?

Tags: intel-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adjusting display geometry in a virtual machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12578/adjusting-display-geometry-in-a-virtual-machine)

I've been having an issue with my monitor - it only displays 640x480. Which is terrible, and making it incredibly difficult to type this question. But when I try running `xrandr` to add resolutions, I get this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  150 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  29
```

I urgently need help - school is starting soon for me and I'd like to work with a halfway decent monitor.

(graphics info):

```
OpenGL vendor string:   Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 8.0.2
```

Comment: what is your graphics card? post result of `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

But, I was finagling around and managed to fix the issue on my own without using xrandr. I followed the instructions in this post and now everything is working beautifully. http://nerdysermons.blogspot.com/2011/11/solve-graphic-driver-errors-unity-3d.html
I guess this can be marked as solved now :)

Comment: Here's how to get modelines for setting geometry with xrandr: http://askubuntu.com/a/12618/3940