# Why can I not set custom resolution for Ubuntu 12.04 running in a virtual machine?

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, resolution

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on the latest VirtualBox release and I cannot change the resolution.

Here are the commands that i run:

-- in Windows

```
VBoxManage setextradata "Ubuntu" "CustomVideoMode1" "1920x1080x32"
```

-- in Ubuntu

```
~$ gtf 1920 1080 32 

# 1920x1080 @ 32.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 35.20 kHz; pclk: 86.17 MHz
  Modeline "1920x1080_32.00"  86.17  1920 1992 2184 2448  1080 1081 1084 1100  -HSync +Vsync

~$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_32.00"  86.17  1920 1992 2184 2448  1080 1081 1084 1100  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

Because this fails, `xrandr --addmode` does not work either. I kept searching the webs and there's a common reccurent theme with a file `/etc/X11/xconf.org` but this is apparently missing from my image.

Also the scroll doesn't work.

Comment: Did you install [Guest Additions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox) correctly? See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/12578/adjusting-display-geometry-in-a-virtual-machine?rq=1

Comment: Takkat is quite correct. Once installed, you can resize the guest like any other window, negating the need for any complex mode switching.

Answer (score 2):

I found that for this VM screen-resizing to work properly on Ubuntu 12.04 guest VMs, you need to have a fairly recent version of the VirtualBox guest additions. It is *not* enough to use the version of VirtualBox distributed in the Ubuntu package repostories. I think that you can use VBoxGuestAdditions 4.1.24 and it will work with Ubuntu 12.04 guests. You need to install the 'dkms' package, possibly also 'kernel-headers', and after that the guest additions 4.1.24 can be installed from the .iso