# Ubuntu Laptop VirtualBox 1920x1080 screen resolution resets after restart

Tags: display-resolution, screen

In settings, under screen resolution, I couldn't find my screen resolution, so I followed the steps [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161202001251/http://geekswithblogs.net/mapfel/archive/2012/03/06/148915.aspx).

That worked. However, I am having the same problem as the guy who commented: after a restart, the resolution goes back to how it was before, and the 1920x1080 option is gone.

I've looked at other answers to similar problems, but none of them seemed to help.

Can somebody please help me fix this?

Thanks,

Undefinedmaster

Comment: Did you install guest editions for the vm?

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/12578/adjusting-display-geometry-in-a-virtual-machine

Answer (score 0):

You have to create or edit your /etc/X11/xorg.conf file. Similar question:

[How can I make xrandr customization permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent)

Comment: How do i create the file? when i right click, the option is faded out

Comment: Never mind, I followed Takkat's comment, and that worked

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**:  This isn't really an answer - it's a comment - but because it's rather long I decided to post it as an answer.

So I followed the link you gave - [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20161202001251/http://geekswithblogs.net/mapfel/archive/2012/03/06/148915.aspx) - and I'm stuck on the last step.

> add the entry to the list of available resolutions
> sudo xrandr --addmode VBOX0 1920x1080

My ubuntu doesn't recognise the name VBOX0. It says:

> xrandr: cannot find output "VBOX0"

[image]

I guess it was not very smart of me to follow a tutorial from 2013 in 2020, and while my ubuntu installation seems to be running just fine and I could leave it in this state, I kind of don't want to.

If you know the right output name or know of another solution, that would be great.

EDIT: Finally got 1920x1080. Here's the answer: https://blog.maskys.com/how-to-set-linuxs-display-resolution-to-1920x1080-in-vmware/