# How do I set the screen resolution to 1600x900 in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, resolution, screen

I'm asking this again because I found this in your site in a related question:

"This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ." Like saying: hey, you are the only one, in the middle of nowhere, and neutrinos were moving faster than light, it's unlikely to happen ever again.

Sounds like nobody could solve it, Canonical got mad and sent everyone to hell...

The solution given once was:

"Solved by installing both of these:

http://intellinuxgraphics.org/2011Q1.html

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11223913&postcount=16

I don't know which of them actually solved the problem - just installed both, rebooted, and it worked."

This reminds me to Windows...

Can you help me community? Is it possible to use a 1600x900 screen resolution in Ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: Can you please clean this up and make a question that is to the point? 90% of this has NO relation to your question and/or is a rant. And to make it worse: the **important** things are missing in this question. Like what kind of videocard you are using. How do you expect any one to be able to answer this? And yes topics on AU get closed based on their content (or lack of).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in general it's possible, given that your graphics card and screen support it.

Prerequisite is of course that you are using a suitable graphics driver. Ubuntu detects most cards just out of the box, yet for some you might need to install the proprietary drivers you can find in the "Additional Drivers" entry of the settings manager.

That being said, there are some exceptions to the rule. Mostly this applies to old (usually built in the early 1990s) monitors that do not report correct EDID information, for which one has to add the corresponding mode lines by hand to xorg.conf. Also, there exist a few exotic graphics chips which are not supported well by Ubuntu (the Intel GMA 500 and GMA 950 are infamous candidates) which might require more work to get them running.

So, if installing the proprietary drivers for your graphics chip does not solve your issue, or there exists no proprietary driver for your graphics card, please report back with more details about your computer, mainly which graphics chip you are using and how your monitor is connected to it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the operating system or Ubuntu limiting the possible screen resolutions but likely your graphics card, or your monitor. Provided the given resolution is supported we can add any resolution including 1600 x 900 to the available screen geometries.

In the answer to the following question I did show how to do that:

- [Adjusting display geometry in a virtual machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12578/adjusting-display-geometry-in-a-virtual-machine)

Below I made a screenshot of an Ubuntu 12.10 resolution of 1900 x 600 including the terminal commands I gave to make this possible:

[image]