# Any tool to set the display resolution into custom size?

Tags: resolution, display, settings, teamviewer

I am using one HD display machine from Teamviewer and my laptop does not support that resolution therefore it is really eye tiring to try. Now I need to change the resolution to that remote machine into my laptop's. Is there any tool to do that. As I see, native tool does not support custom sizing. Would you suggest if there exist?

Answer (score 2):

In *System Settings..* we have an entry *Displays* to let us adjust the screen geometry to values supported by the output device:

[image]

This menu can also be brought up from the command line with

```
gnome-control-center display
```

Comment: any way for non-supported resolutions?

Comment: you could try with this: http://askubuntu.com/a/12618/3940 but after you are in a remote session it may be asking for trouble if the screen had crashed to invisibility.