# Custom screen / monitor size in Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, resolution, display-resolution

After installing guest additions in Virtualbox, I can now get 1024x768, 1440x1050, 1280x960, 1600x1200 sized displays. However, I seem to remember there being some setting which permitted the display to adapt to whatever size the VM's viewport was. Effectively, that would have allowed one to have Ubuntu displaying odd dimensioned virtual monitors like 1400x800 (which seems to fit pretty well on my Windows 7 desktop).

Comment: On virtualbox menu: go to view --> Auto size Guest Display , that can help to get the desired result

Comment: That option is disabled !

Comment: Okay, found the answer... actually, my guest-additions had not been added properly. I hadn't noticed by the kernel module rebuild had failed for a series of reasons. Now with the guest-additions correctly added, the 'Auto size Guest Display' is enabled and working as expected. Thanks @hunch.

Comment: See here for a command-line approach to any odd geometry: http://askubuntu.com/a/12618/3940

Comment: Good point @Takkat. Anyhow, I found the answer. Not sure, what I should do to the question, since I do not see a "Close" button. May be leave it open, and then post an answer myself, if no one does.