# How can I set guest OS screen resolution in virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox

I have installed virtual box on My ubuntu 14.04 machine and I have then  installed ubuntu 14.04 in the VM as a guest OS as well.
I understand I need to correctly install `virtualbox` guest additions to enable the option to change screen resolution.
This may or may not have been successful, so now my question is:

*assuming the guest additions installed successfully* - how do I actually change the screen resolution?
i.e. do I

- go into the `system settings` -> `display` and set from in there? or
- do I go to the virtualbox application in the host OS, select preferences -> and set to `hint` or `automatic`?
- does it just automatically set a sane screen resolution if you successfully install guest additions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adjusting display geometry in a virtual machine?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12578/adjusting-display-geometry-in-a-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 0):

Run your virtual machine and open Terminal to execute:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11
```

Restart your virtual machine: you will see the icons appearing in their natural dimensions (correct resolution)

Comment: thanks. I will try it now. do I run this on the host or the guest OS?

Comment: @user4668401 You must run that on the guest OS

Comment: tried it and it errors out: `virtualbox-guest-x11` has unmet dependencies