# Can I screen record an ubuntu VM in virtualbox at 4k when my host system is 1080p?

Tags: virtualbox, display, display-resolution

I want to record a screen recording of ubuntu in a VM at 4k for people with new monitors however I only have a 1080p screen.

Is there any way to turn the resolution of the VM in virtualbox up to 4k while still fitting it on my 1080p screen?

I have tried manually setting the resolution with xrandr but I get the error "Size index 3840 is too large, there are only 13 sizes" When I listed the sizes the highest one was 2560x1440 but trying to set this resolution failed too.

Comment: What error did you got, and yes, because your monitor is not 4k, it wont work. It's like trying to fill a bucket. You are telling the system your bucket(monitor) is 4k, so it can pour pixels, but because its not, the bucket overflows, and you get an error. This is a hardware limitation, not a software one. Presuming ur monitor doesn't have 4k support.

Comment: I know I wont be able to display the VM at 4k but thats not what i want to do. I just need to record the VM at 4k which should be possible.

Comment: The screen is recorded, there is no stream of data which is coming from your graphics-card/chipset which is of 4k, because of which you cannot do it. Also, such feature is not supported by any known screen-recording program that I know. I wish you good luck, but the probability is quite low, you might wanna start considering/evaluating other options. Good luck!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to run a 4K virtual display in Virtual Box on a smaller screen we need to define the desired resolution (4096 x 2160) first (also [see my answer there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12578/adjusting-display-geometry-in-a-virtual-machine)):

#### Make a 4k virtual screen

1. Calculate the modeline for `xrandr`

   ```
   gtf 3840 2160 60
   Modeline "3840x2160_60.00"  712.34  3840 4152 4576 5312  2160 2161 2164 2235  -HSync +Vsync
   ```
2. Define a new screen geometry mode:

   ```
   xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_60.00"  712.34  3840 4152 4576 5312  2160 2161 2164 2235  -HSync +Vsync
   ```
3. Attach this mode to the Virtual Box virtual screen (e.g. `VGA-0`):

   ```
   xrandr --addmode "VGA-0" 3840x2160_60.00
   ```
4. Apply this mode to the Virtual Screen:

   ```
   xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode "3840x2160_60.00"
   ```

   We can alternatively choose this new geometry from *System settings... > Displays*.

**Note:** Virtual Box should run in windowed mode on a screen having a lower resolution than the new geometry we had defined.

#### Record the desktop

Sadly due to a [bug in Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11758) we may need to disable 3D acceleration in the machine's settings to be able to record the desktop with our [favorite recording software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast).

Below is a scaled down example GIF from a 4K virtual desktop:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will give this a shot later today and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: On that last command I am getting the errors 

    `X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
      Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
      Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (RRSetScreenSize)
      Serial number of failed request:  21
      Current serial number in output stream:  22`

Comment: I restarted the VM and added more gpu memory and it seems to be working now.