# How can I fake HiDPI so I can test my application on it?

Tags: development, open-source, hdpi

I'm a software developer and need to get my software working on HiDPI displays, but I don't have one. How can I fake it so I can see what the users see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing you can create a virtual machine with any desired screen geometry. See these answers on how to do this with Virtual Box:

- [Can I screen record an ubuntu VM in virtualbox at 4k when my host system is 1080p?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694197/can-i-screen-record-an-ubuntu-vm-in-virtualbox-at-4k-when-my-host-system-is-1080)
- [Adjusting display geometry in a virtual machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12578/adjusting-display-geometry-in-a-virtual-machine)